# how to pass more than one argument in pthread_create() C programming Language

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

I am figuring out how to pass more than one argument in pthread_create(). The initialization is

```
pthread_t th[1];
pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, &producer, shmData);
```

and my producer method look like this.

```
void producer(struct ShmData *shmData, sem_t *sem);
```

I basically need to pass both `shmData` along with `sem` when `pthread_creat` is called.
How do I achieve this task?

Comment: Your thread function should take a single pointer to some data structure, which in turn will contain all of the parameters needed. Your `producer` function is not appropriate to be passed to `pthread_create` as is.

Comment: You can't pass extra parameters. But you can use the one `void *` parameter to point to a structure that contains the data you need. Make sure the structure still exists (and hasn't been overwritten) by the time the thread starts - eg maybe malloc it in the creating function, and free it in the thread once it's been used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use struct for that

```
struct thread_arg {
   struct ShmData *shmData;
   sem_t *sem;
};

void producer(struct ShmData *shmData, sem_t *sem);

static void *producer_thread(void *p)
{
    struct thread_arg *arg = p;
    producer(p->shmData, p->sem);
    free(p);
    return NULL;
}

void fx()
{
    pthread_t th[1];
    struct thread_arg *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
    arg->shmData = shmData; // from a variable something
    arg->sem = sem; // from a variable or something
    pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, producer_thread, arg);
}
```